# Is there an analogy for electric current and potential?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

Are there any familiar analogies that might help a layperson to understand electric current and potential?

Comment: [Hydraulic analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy) seems like the way to go here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flow rate of water as a current analog, and height of a water column for a potential analog.  Note that 'potential' is related to potential energy, and when referenced to a 'zero state' or 'ground' is given by 'voltage'. Pipe friction or restrictions in the pipe would be a resistance analog--there would be a 'voltage drop' i.e. a pressure drop.

See (re. Nat):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy

I quote:

"In general, electric potential is equivalent to hydraulic head. This model assumes that the water is flowing horizontally, so that the force of gravity can be ignored. In this case electric potential is equivalent to pressure. The voltage (or voltage drop or potential difference) is a difference in pressure between two points. Electric potential and voltage are usually measured in volts.

Electric current is equivalent to a hydraulic volume flow rate; that is, the volumetric quantity of flowing water over time. Usually measured in amperes.

Electric charge is equivalent to a quantity of water."

"The electronic–hydraulic analogy (derisively referred to as the drain-pipe theory by Oliver Lodge) is the most widely used analogy for "electron fluid" in a metal conductor. Since electric current is invisible and the processes at play in electronics are often difficult to demonstrate, the various electronic components are represented by hydraulic equivalents. Electricity (as well as heat) was originally understood to be a kind of fluid, and the names of certain electric quantities (such as current) are derived from hydraulic equivalents. As with all analogies, it demands an intuitive and competent understanding of the baseline paradigms (electronics and hydraulics)."